# Interaction plot longitudinal data ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, interaction

I have longitudinal data, the first few observations of my data:

```
           pid arm pday   hb
9  MOB2004_002  SP    0 11.5
12 MOB2004_002  SP    3  9.1
13 MOB2004_002  SP    7  8.9
14 MOB2004_002  SP   14  8.5
15 MOB2004_002  SP   28 11.0
16 MOB2004_002  SP   42  8.6
```

I have made an interaction plot as follows:

```
interaction.plot(q2$pday,q2$arm,q2$hb,fun=mean,ylab="Parasite Density" ,xlab="Day")
```

[image: interaction plot]

I would like to replicate this plot with ggplot, but I am unsure how to do this, any help would greatly be appreciated. I am new to ggplot and have been able to produce the following:

```
p1 <- ggplot(data = q2, aes(x = pday, y = hb, group = arm))+ geom_line()
```

[image: ggplot]

I understand that the interaction.plot function plots the mean of the response, but I am unsure how to get ggplot to do this.

Comment: It looks like there is an additional grouping in your data that is not accounted for in ggplot2 (maybe the `pid` variable? If so, use `group = interaction(pid, arm)`). As it is now, there are likely multiple observation from the same group at the same day, causing these vertical lines. Also, based on the y-axis range, this seems unlikely the same data you've used in the interaction plot and in ggplot2.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. However, your suggestion produces a plot with multiple lines (I assume one for each subject).

Comment: Yes that is what I would have expected. If you want to summarise data by group, you can look  into `?stat_summary`.